# Is it possible to share device list via SyncThing itself?

Tags: syncthing

I have several devices connected via SyncThing. Let's call them A, B, C, D and E. I have a folder that's shared among all of them. Now, if I want to add a new device (F) and set the same connections, I have to

1. open new device F and add 5 old devices
2. on each device, add F
3. share the folder from one old device (say A) to F
4. accept it at F
5. repeat 3. and 4. (but may be share in the opposite direction) for each other device (B, C, D, E)

That is a *lot* of steps. Can this be done in fewer steps somehow?

I've tried the ~recommender option for A (not sure what is the exact term in English) but it doesn't seem to do a thing.